# How to compare User interface elements of a website after a code deployment?

Tags: user-interface, testing

I want to compare a website before and after a code deployment for any change in UI elements. Is there any tool online which allows for such comparisons?

Comment: What do you exactly mean by UI elements? Only parts of your HTML or all of it? Do yiu want to compare elements which are also created by JS after page load?...

Comment: I would rather say the visual elements seen by an end user for example font size, color and alignment, spacing of buttons, icon sizes and its placement on the web page, image sizes, labels on buttons, etc.

Answer (score 2):

As per your comment on Yan's question, I think you are looking for a way to automate Layout Testing of your website.

If Yes, here is a way to automate layout testing of a web application using Galen Framework. Open source solution for layout testing.

This tool has its own language and is very easy to learn and understand. It is a Selenium based and you can run test in Selenium Grid, [Sauce Labs](https://saucelabs.com/) if you want to test your application in different browsers. even you can use chrome driver or IEDriver for running it locally without using Selenium grid or [Sauce Labs](https://saucelabs.com/)

This tool gets the location of specified element on page and check them relatively to each other.

Example: If you want to check icon sizes and its placement on the web page (lets assume it is inside header), you can do it like this:

First define object using any of the available locators(css path, ID, xpath)

```
=======================================
header          css     #header
icon            id      icon
=======================================
```

Now state where exactly your icon should exist inside header and what should be it's height and width. (I have assumed all the values here)

```
icon
    inside: header 5px top, 10px right
    width:  20px
    height: 25px
```

This tool can also be used to test responsive designs.

You can find complete documentation on official website http://galenframework.com

The best part is you can even create JAVA Tests. Galen JavaScript API is also available along with the sample projects in github.

At my place HTML designers write the specifications (in Galen language) of web pages and in the later stages of application lifecycle same specifications are used by developer/testers

As you mentioned that you want to
*compare a website before and after a code deployment for any change in UI elements*, you can use html reports generated by Galen after each run/test.

Answer (score 0):

I believe you don't want to compare the changes manually  but want to automate the process. You can use selenium web driver to find the elements on the web page and then test if they present on the changed one. [Applitools](http://applitools.com/) provides the framework that allows to test the image changes combined with the selenium code.

Comment: Thank you Eugene, this was a very helpful idea